# Performance comparison if / else vs state change vs noop in HTMLCanvasElement render loop

Tags: typescript, if-statement, canvas, html5-canvas, no-op

In a project related to `HTMLCanvasElement`, I have a base class `Object2d` which stores object's state with many options, e.g. `rotation`, `debug`, etc., that affect the rendering phase.

A typical render function for the instances of this class would be:

```js
public render() : void {

  const ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D = this._canvas.getContext('2d);

  if (this.rotation !== 0) {
    ctx.rotate(this.rotation);
  } 
    
  this._drawObject(ctx);
    
  if (this.debug) {
    this._renderDebug(ctx);
  }
    
  if (this.rotation !== 0) {
    ctx.rotate(-this.rotation);
  }

}
```

Another way, would pass by changing the context state even if `rotation` is 0 (but the `if` remains with `debug` in this example):

```js
public render() : void {

  const ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D = this._canvas.getContext('2d);

  ctx.rotate(this.rotation);
    
  this._drawObject(ctx);
    
  if (this.debug) {
    this._renderDebug(ctx);
  }
    
  ctx.rotate(-this.rotation);

}
```

I choosed (and I may be wrong!) to switch functions according to the value of - in this case - rotation and debug:

```js
private _beginRotation = noop; // 'noop' is a function that does nothing.
private _endRotation = noop;
private _renderDebug = noop;

// Happens only when changing rotation value.
public set rotation(value: number) {

  this._rotation = value;

  if (this._rotation !== 0) {

    // Will rotate the context.
    this._beginRotation = this.myBeginRotationActualMethod;

    // Will restore the context rotation.
    this._endRotation = this.myEndRotationActualMethod;
  
  } else {

    this._beginRotation = noop;
    this._endRotation = noop;

  }

}

// Happens only when changing 'debug' value.
public set debug(value: boolean) {

  this._debug = value;

  if (this._debug) {
    this._renderDebug = this.myDebugActualMethod;
  } else {
    this._renderDebug = noop;
  }

}

public render() : void {

  const ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D = this._canvas.getContext('2d);

  this._beginRotation(); // Calls noop or the actual context rotation function.

  this._drawObject(ctx);

  this._renderDebug();

  this._endRotation(); // Again: noop, or the actual context restore function.

}
```

My questions are:

- Is calling an empty function faster than passing by a `if` condition?
- Is changing the state, i.e. by calling `ctx.rotate` even with 0 value, faster than passing by the `noop` function or the `if` statement?

Comment: There is no single answer to that kind of questions. You can try to run benchmarks with all the options, on various systems, under various conditions and see if there is a clear winner, then remember to do the same tests in a few months when implementations will have changed and new devices are available to see if it changed. But at this level that's certainly *just* "micro-optimization". I really don't expect any measurable difference between any of these options. My best advice would be to write the code that's the clearest to you and the easiest to maintain.

Comment: Thank you @Kaiido. For the time being, my intuition is that avoiding a state change will free the GPU and will not affect too much the CPU but, again, I may be wrong. I'll do benchmarks, but an insight from a HTMLCanvas / GPU expert would be of great help to understand what's happening under the hood... Thanks again!